# how to modify largePageDataBytes in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to change largePageDataBytes
I understand that this will worsen performance.
I tried the following in next.config.js

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  /* config options here */
  //largePageDataBytes: 128 * 1000, // 128KB by default
  largePageDataBytes: 128 * 100000,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and got

```
warn - Invalid next.config.js options detected:
```

Where and how do I change the largePageDataBytes?

Answer (score 23):

According to the [code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v14.0.3/packages/next/src/export/index.ts#L491) it's expected to be in the `experimental` property for now.

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  experimental: {
    largePageDataBytes: 128 * 100000,
  },
  ...
}
```