# NextJS Firestore fetch with SSR having huge file size

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to pull data from firestore through NextJS SSR. However, the data size is really large and gets frequent warnings.

**Is there a solution to pull small chunks but complete data iteratively?**

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

  const collectionRef = collection(db, 'posts');

  const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy('id', 'asc'));

  const querySnapShot = await getDocs(q);

  let posts = [];

  querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
    posts(doc.data());
  });

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

The error I am getting is given below.

**Warning: data for page "/profile" is 15.3 MB which exceeds the threshold of 128 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/large-page-data**

Comment: fetch your data with `CSR`.

Comment: You can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73889992/how-to-modify-largepagedatabytes-in-next-js) to modify `largePageData` in `next.config.js`

Comment: @MoeinMoeinnia trying to not use CSR since the same load then will be on client side.  Is it possible to iteratively render the payload.

Comment: Have you considered fetching a smaller subset in `getStaticProps` and then fetch the rest as needed on the client-side?

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are fetching a lot of data (more than 128kb) in getStaticProps,As mentioned in this github [thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39880#discussioncomment-3473149) reduce the data to essentials before passing it as data as props. check the size by running this on the console: `document.getElementById("__NEXT_DATA__").text` transform that data before you return it in `getStaticProps` to keep only the values you need

You can also check this github [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40606)